# Svelte bound prop not updating in reactive statement

Tags: svelte

I have a svelte component like so

```html
<script lang='ts'>
  export let foo = 100;

  let bar = 10
  let prevbar = 10;  

  $: if (bar !== prevbar) {
    foo = 1;
    prevbar = bar;
  }
</script>

<div>
  <Dropdown bind:bar />
</div>
```

Basically what is not happening is that a parent that this component does not see `foo` change. Is there a problem assigning `foo = 1` inside of a reactive statement?

```html
// foo never changes to 1 
<div>
  <MyComponent bind:foo/>
</div>
```

---

It looks like even `prevbar` does not properly update..

---

I'm having a real hard time re-producing the same issue in REPL but here's pretty much the same question.. This may be something I just don't yet understand about reactivity and bound variables in svelte.

In this example below I want to understand why after setting `page =  666` in `Foo.svelte` is `App.svelte` not updated? If it's two-way binding shouldn't everyone's update update each other?

https://svelte.dev/repl/eb50b71311134482b65bd035e2ffd97e?version=3.55.0

Comment: Can you create a complete example, ideally with an additional REPL link? Something has to change `bar` or `prevbar` so the `if` passes, where/how does that happen?

Comment: @H.B. attached a link

Comment: Reduced example https://svelte.dev/repl/eb50b71311134482b65bd035e2ffd97e?version=3.55.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this is [this bug](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/8103) which should be fixed already but is not published yet.

The REPL works as expected [with version 3.53.1](https://svelte.dev/repl/eb50b71311134482b65bd035e2ffd97e?version=3.53.1)

Comment: Oh dang was not expecting that! Thanks, guess I will have to wait a bit.